# How to get pakcages latest versions shown and easily update them on click in .yaml file flutter and vscode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, yaml

Here are the dew screenshots that are working in VSCODE but I am unable to get them be shown in another PC and laptop, please tell how to show or enable it
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try `flutter pub outdated`. Otherwise, did you install `flutter` and `dart ` plugins for VSCode?

Comment: Most likely u're using a vscode extension that shows this. I did find this link that shows exactly what ur showing in an extension called "Pubspec Assets" package... check it https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1977#issuecomment-947629693 
.... but FYI I do use it but I don't see those things, maybe it needs some extra things to do

Comment: Yes, I have flutter dart and pubspec assist installed....but this shows to me...but on my new laptop it won't show at all...it's helpful and the command flutter pub is outdated etc... only update the pubspec.lock file not the actual file

Comment: found it, see my answer

Answer (score 6):

So i found it, it was a package named " VERSION LENS"